# Is it possible to make fiddler not buffer large requests

Tags: debugging, post, https, fiddler, large-data

I have an app that uses HTTPS and I can successfully use fiddler to view and modify the decrypted traffic. The app often does post requests of very large files (hundreds of MB or more) and fiddler seems to use loads of memory and become slow to respond when these large post requests are happening.

I'm hoping there is some way to not log the request/response body and just log the headers.

I have tried using stream mode which seems to make no difference; the body of the large request is still logged

I also added these two lines to the OnBeforeRequest function:

```
oSession["log-drop-request-body"] = "yes";
oSession["log-drop-response-body"] = "yes";
```

This results in the body not being logged after the request/response has completed, but while it is still ongoing, the body is logged which is (I assume) what causes the problem if the request is very large.

Is there anything else that I can try to make it behave better with these large posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddler inherently buffers request bodies before sending them; if you set `log-drop-request-body`, it will drop the body as soon as it is transmitted.

In contrast, if you have Response Streaming enabled and `log-drop-response-body` set, Fiddler will drop each chunk of the response body as it is read from the server and passed to the client.

Having said that, there's no reason that Fiddler would "become slow to respond" in this situation, and I've contacted you about this on the Telerik Forum where you copied this question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Eric! It's great to get a response on SO from the actual Dev of the product in question. I didn't mean to post in both forums, but the one in the Telerik forum was originally "quarantined" because it thought my question was SPAM. I'll accept this answer and carry on the discussion in the Telerik forum (here for any SO users that come across this answer in future: http://www.telerik.com/forums/is-it-possible-to-not-buffer-requests)

Comment: FWIW, request streaming was added to a later version of Fiddler; see the `BufferRequest` property.